# Странные ошибки, которых ранее не возникало

Tags: c#, winforms

Объясните, пожалуйста, как исправить ошибки? Сделал как здесь описано, но при нажатии на кнопку сообщение не выводится https://metanit.com/sharp/windowsforms/1.1.php

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace HW_1
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }
        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Привет");
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: покажите  InitializeComponent();

Comment: Как это показать?

Comment: Я дал ответ посмотрите туда

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Вы должны были кликнут на кнопке

"Наведем указатель мыши на кнопку и щелкнем по ней двойным щелчком."

либо в окне свойства (F4) button1 на событие OnClick установить значание button1_Click